# Querying user's status from an external site?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have a web app where a person would like to post little updates to their website. I was wondering if, so he wouldn't have to worry about updating it separately, it could just go and get his facebook status, and use it as the text there.

I'm using Ruby on Rails and CoffeeScript.

## EDIT

Sorry, I found a quick jquery tutorial on it, this just makes no alert at all:

```
$.get 'https://graph.facebook.com/pgun15?fields=statuses.limit(1).fields(message)', (data) -> 
    console.log data
```

## EDIT

The above code gives the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (OK) https://graph.facebook.com/PGUN15?fields=statuses.limit(1).fields(message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem #1) you're calling "facebok.com"

Problem #2) Use console.log() instead of alert() -- it prints to the developer console instead of opening up a popup window; much easier to read the results that way.

Problem #3) $.get is asynchronous -- it returns an object with functions you can call when the data arrives. In your case, you'd want to do something like:

```
$.get("http://facebook.com/me?fields=statuses.limit(1)", function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

or in coffeescript:

```
$.get "http://facebook.com/me?fields=statuses.limit(1)", (data)->
  console.log data
```

documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized I'm using coffeescript, do you know how to write your answer that way?

Comment: Instead of facebook.com, what should I be calling?